# im trying to add the average of something to a list, but im getting a NoneType error

Tags: python, list, append, nonetype

I want to add the variable 'average' to the list called avgList, but im getting a the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

```
tempList = []
nameList = []
avgList = []
ctr = 0
ctrr = 0
while ctrr <12:
    name = raw_input("Enter team name: ")
    ctrr += 1
    ctr = 0
    while ctr <8:
        score = input("Enter Scores: ")
        ctr += 1
        tempList.append(score)
    summ = sum(tempList)
    average = summ/len(tempList)
    avgList = avgList.append(int(average))
print max(avgList)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
avgList = avgList.append(int(average))
```

`append()` returns `None`, so after the first time through your loop, `avgList` is no longer your list, but `None`.

To avoid this, don't assign the return value back to `avgList`. Just:

```
avgList.append(int(average))
```

You did this correctly earlier in your script.

Answer (score 0):

That's caused by this line:

```
avgList = avgList.append(int(average))
```

Change it to be this:

```
avgList.append(int(average))
```